# c# linq: how to retrieve pieces of data from a returned record

Tags: c#, linq

So i have the query:

```
 var query =
                from product in db.LUT_ProductInfos
                where product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container
                select flavor;
```

which is returning 1 record (it should always return one record). How do i pull individual attribute values from the result? For example, if it returns 1 record with 3 columns like firstName lastName phoneNumber, and i want to do something with each of the values like

```
string fName = firstName
string lName = lastName
int pNumber = phoneNumber
```

without getting into data mapping for objects, what is the most direct way to extract those values from the result variable query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query =
            from product in db.LUT_ProductInfos
            where product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container
            select new {product.Foo, product.flavor.Bar, ...};

var row = query.First(); // or Single(), FirstOrDefault(), SingleOrDefault()

string foo = row.Foo;
int bar = row.Bar;
...
```

This has the advantage that only the desired properties are included in the `SELECT` statement, and there are no hidden additional round-trips (lazy loading).

Answer (score 1):

```
var singleResult =
            (from product in db.LUT_ProductInfos
            where product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container
            select flavor).Single();
string fName = singleResult.firstName
string lName = singleResult.lastName
int pNumber = singleResult.phoneNumber
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to select the product and not the flavor.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = db.LUT_ProductInfos
    .SingleOrDefault(product => product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container);

if (row != null)
{
    string firstName = row.fName;
    string lastName = row.lName;
    string phone = row.pNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to do this is to recode like this:

```
var query =
                (from product in db.LUT_ProductInfos
                where product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container
                select flavor).FirstOrDefault();
```

it will return the first matched record. If there's no matched record it will retutn null value, otherwise it returns an object of LUT_ProductInfos class. you can also skip records as you wish like this:

```
var query =
                (from product in db.LUT_ProductInfos
                where product.flavor == flavor && product.Container == container
                select flavor).Skip(25).FirstOrDefault();
```